# KeyError: 'begins_at'

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

```
TICKERS = ['^GSPC','^IXIC','^GDAXI', '^FTSE']
ind_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in TICKERS:
    ind_data [f] = wb.DataReader(f,data_source = 'robinhood',start = '1998-01-01') ['close_price'].values
```

---

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-813-4985fcf38db5> in <module>()
      2 ind_data = pd.DataFrame()
      3 for f in TICKERS:
----> 4     ind_data [f] = wb.DataReader(f,data_source = 'robinhood',start = '1998-01-01') ['close_price'].values


KeyError: 'begins_at'
```

Comment: Is that really the full traceback?  I don't see where `'begins_at'` is referenced.

Comment: @JohnGordon its not letting me post the entire error

Answer (score 0):

I was using dash and I encountered the same problem.

this is a very helpful document of dataframe
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pandas-datareader/latest/pandas-datareader.pdf

I still couldn't get stock price from robinhood to work, but I successfully displayed my chart with other API in my case, It was quandl.

Few things I got from reading the doc given above.

1. each broker offers different length of data. eg. robinhood only offers 1 years. ( this doesn't seem to be a problem tho. even if you asked for more than 1 year, i will just give you 1 year data)
2. Symbols used in each broker is different. 
   eg. morningstar (no longer available) used aapl for Apple stock. quandl used WIKI/AAPL.

I am sure that there are more exception like those I give above, but that's all I know for now because I only took a look at the doc less than 10 mins.

Comment: thanks, its still giving me the following error after using the csv as a data source "ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with all the ticker symbols that contained dashes and caret.

Also if the ticker symbol is not supported by Robinhood, than you will get the same 'begins_at' massage.

Here is an example the ticker symbol IMIO is not supported by Robinhood and will give the same massage.
`import pandas_datareader.data as web
 web.DataReader("IMIO", 'robinhood')`